# Flask Images in Various Subfolders

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a simple Flask web application which stores small PDFs / JPEGs for each user. Since the files are unique to each user, I do not want to simply store them in the "static" folder as flask requires. Instead, I have a "Users" folder, within which a subfolder is created for each user & their files are stored.

I want to be able to do the following, but the image does not display:

```
{% block main %}
   <img src="/users/bob/test.JPG"
{% endblock %}
```

However, if i save that same test.JPG in static and use the following, it does work:

```
{% block main %}
   <img src="/static/test.JPG"
{% endblock %}
```

My file structure is:

```
ProjectFolder
   static
      styles.css
   templates
      index.html
      ...
   users
      bob
         image.jpg
         ...
      sam
      ...
   venv
   app.py
   helpers.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask only supports downloading static files from the static folder by default.
However, if you add your own endpoint, you can download files from a folder of your choosing. For security reasons, you should ensure that access to certain regions of your file system is limited. I also recommend using a subdirectory of the [instance path](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.instance_path) for this. Thus, the files are separated from your application.

```
import os
from flask import Flask 
from flask import send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'users')

try:
    os.makedirs(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
except OSError:
    pass

@app.route('/users/<path:filename>')
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory(
        app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 
        filename
    )
```

To request one of the files, you can either use `url_for` or specify the path directly.

```
<img src="{{ url_for('.download', filename='bob/image.jpg') }}" />
```